# 404 when accessing Design Automation API v3 through HttpClient

Tags: c#, autodesk-designautomation

Running calls to the Design Automation API in Postman works just fine but when I try to make the same calls in C# using HttpClient they fail with a 404 that seems to actually hide an authentication error:

```
{ 
    "developerMessage":"The requested resource does not exist.",
    "userMessage":"",
    "errorCode":"ERR-002",
    "more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/err-002"
}
```

That link leads to an authentication error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>1F52E60A45AEF429</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        [ Some base64 ]
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

I'm following examples for how to use HttpClient, but I may be missing something. I successfully get the access token, run

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east")
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(TokenType, AccessToken);
```

then

```
var result = await client.GetAsync("/v3/forgeapps/me");
```

and the above json is the result's content. I use the same access token in Postman and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap up the endpoint, headers, and httpmethod in the HttpRequestMessage. Then send it and assign it to HttpResponseMessage.

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/")
};

//throw the endpoint and HttpMethod here. Could also be HttpMethod.Post/Put/Delete (for your future reference)
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "v3/forgeapps/me");

//also maybe try throwing the headers in with the request instead of the client
request.Headers.Add(TokenType, AccessToken);

// send the request, assign to response
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

//then, we can grab the data through the Content
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Had to do request.Headers.Add("Authorization",$"{TokenType} {AccessToken}"); but it did work. Now just to figure out why.

Comment: Wow the / needs to be at the end of the BaseAddress instead of at the beginning of the get endpoint. Thanks for the help!

Comment: hahaha! nice! glad it worked for you! computers are weird and picky